# What makes an operational semantics good?

Tags: operational-semantics

Some papers define an operational semantics of a programming language. That is nice, but what makes such a semantics fit for the purpose?

An idea is to have a progress theorem, i.e. well-formed expression is either a value or a reduction can take place

another is type preservation, that an reduction preserves the type of an expression.

What else is a test for the adequateness of a semantics? What should I prove about it?

Comment: Progress and type preservation only make sense for typed languages.

Comment: I am interested in typed languages

Comment: Not to answer the question, but the operational semantics can be made executable and run against a test suite for the language – the paper "An Executable Formal Semantics of PHP" by  Daniele Filaretti and Sergio Maffeis (ECOOP 2014) tests their extensive semantics of PHP against Zend PHP's test suite.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have it a bit backwards: proving type preservation is a good property of the *type system* with respect to the operational semantics, rather than the opposite.

Alternately: the whole point of a programing language is the ability to use it to perform some computational task. Because of this, the operational semantics is one of the *requirements* of having a programing language. The only real "fitness test" you need is

> Can I write the programs I want using this language?

You might then want to prove that say, a *compiler* is correctly implemented by showing that the computational behavior of (well-behaved) code is equivalent in some sense to the operational semantics, but again, here I would take the semantics themselves to be primal rather than the opposite.

In certain fields of mathematics, notably in the area which studies the [propositions-as-types correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), one might be more interested in the static semantics (the type system) and have the operational semantics more as an afterthought, where progress, preservation and termination have consequences on the type system as a logic (typically, that the logic is consistent).

But again, usually the operational semantics is primitive, and it is well-defined exactly when it enables the programmer to write the program she wishes to write (and possibly prevents some "bad" programs).

Comment: I understand all the above, but is there any mathematical test on it? My idea is to formalise such a semantics in a theorem prover and then prove ... what?

Comment: What is your goal in performing such a formalization? An operational semantics is like a definition in Mathematics: not all that useful unless you have a motivation for it. If you're looking for *suggestions*, then I'd have to say that stackexchange is not really the right forum for this, though I'd suggest looking at some examples of such developments, e.g. this nice one here: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Smallstep.html

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of what an _operational semantics_ is for. It has nothing to do with how program-in-able a language is.

Comment: My point is that an operational semantics *is* (the crucial part of) the definition of a programing language, and so is only useful insomuch as the programing language itself is useful.

Comment: The programming language may not be useful for programming, it may be for studying a particular aspect of concurrency or memory management or for demonstrating that a particular type system is sound. Also, most programming languages are not given an operational semantics (in the formal sense). Most operational semantics are defined independently of the language implementation. So in short, I completely disagree.

Comment: So you completely disagree that the point of a programing language is to write programs? Note that I'm not advocating that those programs need to actually run on a machine and be part of say, a facebook app. But in the abstract, it's important to know which programs can be written. And I agree that many language designers *in practice* often neglect to define a formal semantics for their language. However this is usually a bad decision, and later people struggle to come up with a formal description of the operational semantics, just to be able to prove things about it, e.g. adequacy wrt...

Comment: ...the compiler, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @cody My main point is that adequacy of operational semantics and usefulness of a programming language are orthogonal concepts. For example, the operational semantics for the WHILE language presented in Nielson and Nielson's semantics text book describes a language too primitive to program in. On the other hand, Scala, a very useful language, lacks an operational semantics.

Comment: I don't disagree with your point that a programming language is used to write programs, but that does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @DaveClarke: As I understand it, the question was roughly "what is an adequate operational semantics?". The point I was making is that *operational semantics comes first* and then all *other* semantic properties (typing, compiler correctness) need to be proven adequate wrt the operational semantics! This is in the ideal world, of course, since sadly a lot of people design language compilers without a formal semantics in mind (I would argue that they start with an *informal* semantics though).